# Combining DISTINCT and ORDER BY when ordering by nested property with JPA

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have a JPQL query that is looking for distinct records with pageable. There are situations where the pageable sort will be a property in a nested class.

```
public class Entity1 {
  @Id
  private long id;
  
  @ManyToOne
  private Entity2 entity2;
}
```

```
public class Entity2 {
  @Id
  private long id;
  
  private String fieldToSort;
}
```

```
public interface Entity1Repository extends JpaRepository<Entity1, Long> {
  Page<Entity1> findDistinct(Pageable pageable);
}
```

If I call the query sorting by `entity2`, the correct result is returned. However, when I try and sort by by `entity2.fieldToSort`, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list
```

If I remove the `DISTINCT` restriction, the query runs fine, but returns an `Entity1` record for each `Entity2`.

What is the best way of handling sorting by sub fields, when requiring a distinct record for each of the main entities?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved this by using a nested query in the respository:

```
@Query("select e1 from Entity1 e1 where e1 in (select e1 from Entity1 e1 left join e1.entity2 e2)")
Page<Entity1> findDistinctCustom(Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: This is not efficient at all. You can simply solve this by using JOIN FETCH.
This tells hibernate to load the nested entity together with your main one.

Answer (score 0):

You can simple use JOIN **FETCH**:

```
SELECT e1 FROM Entity1 e1 LEFT JOIN FETCH e1.entity2 e2.
```

Using JOIN with FETCH allows associations or collections of values to be initialized along with their parent objects using a single select.

[https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html#:~:text=A%20%22fetch%22%20join%20allows%20associations%20or%20collections%20of%20values%20to%20be%20initialized%20along%20with%20their%20parent%20objects%20using%20a%20single%20select](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html#:%7E:text=A%20%22fetch%22%20join%20allows%20associations%20or%20collections%20of%20values%20to%20be%20initialized%20along%20with%20their%20parent%20objects%20using%20a%20single%20select).

It is way more elegant than writing a sub query.